# Getting Param Type from posted CGI content (or dealing with checkbox on/off values)

Tags: html, perl, checkbox, cgi

I have a checkbox in my HTML that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SHORT>" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=ELSE>">
<input type="checkbox" name="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SHORT>" id="checkbox-2" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=FLAG>" class="checkbox mid-margin-left">
<label for="checkbox-2" class="label"><TMPL_VAR NAME="NAME"></label>
```

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish here is for one value to be sent if the checkbox is checked, and another to be sent if the checkbox is not checked (a default value basically). Now, this is dynamic, so I am really unable to do something in the CGI to say, "If this is defined then it means this, and if it's not then it means something else."

Anyway, when I leave the box unchecked, I get the value from the hidden input. However, when I check it I get both values. Now, I could say, "If this has more than one value, then the value to use is the second one." But, what if I am getting the value of a select list that accepts multiple values? In that situation I don't want to say take the 2nd value, because all values sent are valid.

So, what I am trying to say is this: "If it is a checkbox, and there is more than one value, then take the second value; otherwise, take the first."

Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe I am not doing this right? Any suggestions on a better way to accomplish this? I don't want to use a radio button for a boolean (yes/no), but if that's the only way, then so be it.

Comment: I decided to show two different approaches, hence the two separate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want JS, I would suggest you change your form so there's an alternate value for every field with a prefix on the name:

```html
<form id="myform" method='post' action="/echo/json/">
    <input type="hidden" name= "alternate-foo" value="foo not selected" />
    <input type="hidden" name="alternate-bar" value="first bar" />
    <p>Foo <input type='checkbox' name='foo' id='foo' value='foo selected' /></p>
    <p>
        <select name='bar' id='bar' multiple>
            <option value='first bar'>bar 1</option>
            <option value='second bar'>bar 2</option>
            <option value='third bar'>bar 3</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /></p>
</form>
```

In your Perl code, you could do something like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

$q->param( 'foo', $q->param('alternate-foo') ) unless $q->param('foo');
$q->param( 'bar', $q->param('alternate-bar') ) unless $q->param('bar');
```

Or, to be more dynamic:

```perl
use 5.014;
foreach my $alt ( grep { /^alternate-/ } $q->param ) {
  my $name = $alt =~ s/^alternate-//r;
  $q->param( $name, $q->param( $alt )) unless $q->param($name);
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to upvote your response, but I do appreciate your input greatly. I ended up using your input and it works exactly how I want it to work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works. :) If this helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left below the votes so other people can see it was the correct solution. See the [faq#howtoask] for more info. You can upvote once you have 15 [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with JavaScript and jQuery for convenience. Only downside is, it will not work if your clients have disabled JS.

Your form could remain pretty much the same. I made a simple example. Make sure there are ids on everything.

```html
<form id="myform" method='post' action="/echo/json/">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-foo" value="foo not selected" />
    <p>Foo <input type='checkbox' name='foo' id='foo' value='foo selected' /></p>
    <p>
        <select name='bar' id='bar' multiple>
            <option value='first bar'>bar 1</option>
            <option value='second bar'>bar 2</option>
            <option value='third bar'>bar 3</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /></p>
</form>
```

Now here's the JS code, which should be placed below the form or inside an event handler for the `load` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#myform").submit(function(){
        // if checkbox is not checked, change value and check so it's transmitted
        if (! $("#foo").is(":checked")) {
            $("#foo").val($("#hidden-foo").val()).prop('checked', true);
        }

        // take first option if no option is selected
        if( $("#bar option:selected").length == 0 ) {
            $("#bar option:first").attr('selected','selected');
        }
    })
});
```

It's pretty straight-forward:

- if the checkbox is not ticked, it will change it's value to the one of the hidden field and tick it.
- if no option is selected, it will select the first one

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WzAhE/) to demonstrate. You should open your Firebug console to see the output.

It should now be fairly easy to turn this into something dynamic that can handle all form fields without your template engine having to meddle with the JS code.

Comment: And thank you for showing me more than one way to do this. I was using something similar to this before, but JS disabled browsers are what made this not an option for me.